# .NET DynamicData in production systems

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have to decide is DynamicData is a right thing to me. The goal is to build web UI for CRIUD to DB. I already have EF4 codefirst model for this DB.

Things to think about: a lot of ugly things (can't render ComplexTypes for ex) and workarounds (DateTime controls, binary columns, what is next?)

Have you ever used DynamicData-projects in production systems? What is your experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out these very similar questions here:

[Are there any real-world case studies on the ASP.NET Dynamic Data Framework (DDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871515/are-there-any-real-world-case-studies-on-the-asp-net-dynamic-data-framework-ddf)

[ASP.NET Dynamic Data PRO and CONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874669/asp-net-dynamic-data-pro-and-cons)

[Do you think ASP.Net Dynamic Data is worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513775/do-you-think-asp-net-dynamic-data-is-worth-it)

In summary, **it doesn't sound like many folks have used DD for production systems**. The consensus seems to be that it is better for small projects and RAD apps.